# ERROR: Permission to xyz/private-repo.git denied to x

Tags: git, github

I am using two git accounts on the same Mac, one for Work and one for Personal dev. I used to use ssh access for the accounts. I generated the SSHs and added them to the config file.

I am using the this config file

```
Host x-GitHub
    HostName github.com
    User x
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/siyum/.ssh/x-GitHub
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes

Host Nethsara
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/siyum/.ssh/nethsara
```

Now I cloned a private repo from my personal one, Which is Nethsara and it cloned successfully.

I used this to clone

```
% git clone git@Nethsara:Nethsara/private-repo.git
```

But when I tried to commit and push a change it is giving me this error.

> ERROR: Permission to Nethsara/private-repo.git denied to x. fatal:
> Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

My global username is already set to Nethsara.

> % git config --global user.name
> Nethsara

What could be go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple things you can fix.

First, SSH connections to GitHub *all* happen with the username `git`. Either change your `~/.ssh/config` to include the line `User git` instead of that `User x`, or remove that line and be sure that all remotes include `git@` before your custom hostnames.

Second, since you're working with multiple identities, add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to each stanza. This will prevent the agent from even bothering with other known identities, and only use the one specified in the config file.

Finally, you can test SSH connections to GitHub with `ssh -T git@x-GitHub` and `ssh -T git@Nethsara` - if things are configured properly in your `~/.ssh/config`, you should get a message with the correct GitHub username for each.

Comment: Thanks Jim, This worked. That first one was generated by SourceTree, thats why I kept it untouched.